# What is this song in Episode 459 of Naruto Shippuden?

Tags: naruto, music

In Episode 459 what is the background music that plays about 20:00 to last?

Answer (score 1):

The exact version your asking about was an unreleased OST, but it is known as Kaguyas theme. The full song begins ~18min mark on episode 459 and you can listen to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2NyvBjj378)

Credits to a user on [this Naruto discussion board](https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/4hze5d/naruto_shippuden_episode_459_links_and_discussion/d317tkw/) for finding it